# NoClassDefFoundError in Java: com/google/common/base/Function

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, runtime-error

When I executing the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http:www.yahoo.com");
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError ex) {
        System.out.println("error: " + ex.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

I'm facing the following error:

> error:[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@80f4cb
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

Could someone help me to find the solution or reason for this?

Comment: try using the `ex.printStackTrace()` method.

Answer (score 112):

I had the same problem, and finally I found that I forgot to add the [selenium-server-standalone-version.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server-standalone). I had only added the client jar, [selenium-java-version.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java).

Comment: Why is the standalone jar needed? I am running it only on a single machine?

Comment: And versions of both jars should better be matched.

Answer (score 24):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when the JRE can't find a class. In your case, it can't find the class `com.google.common.base.Function`, which you most probably did not add to your classpath.

### EDIT

After downloading the following libraries:

- Selenium: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list
- Guava: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/list
- Apache HttpComponents: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
- JSON jar: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/versionInfo/21653

and unzipping them and putting all JAR files in a folder called `lib`, the test class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http:www.yahoo.com");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ran without any problems.

You can compile and run the class as follows:

```
# compile and run on Linux & Mac
javac -cp .:lib/* Test.java 
java -cp .:lib/* Test

# compile and run on Windows
javac -cp .;lib/* Test.java 
java -cp .;lib/* Test
```

Comment: This is the most general answer if one wants to run Selenium test for the first time, because all mentioned libraries are needed.

Comment: @Bart Kiers I am running `javac -classpath C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar; C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar Test.java` and then `java Test` but returns: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver at Test.main(Test.java:7) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Firefox` I am with that a few hours; Any ideas please? Thanks! (Win7)

Comment: @Bart Kiers Thanks for your response. I change the pathclass to `javac -classpath "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar;C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-firefox-driver-2.42.2.jar" Test.java` But returns the same error. I download `firefox-driver` from this [link](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver/2.42.2). Any new ideas:)?

Comment: +1 for noticing that you need to add the classpath to both the compile and run command. The first was obvious but the second, for me, for some reason, wasn't.

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same error and after the investigation, I found that library selenium-api 2.41.0 requires guava 15.0 but it was overridden by an older version so I declared guava 15.0 as a direct dependency by adding following configuration in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is the step that worked for me also. I did not have to do anything else

Answer (score 7):

you don't have the ["google-collections"](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) library on your [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

There are a number of [ways to add libraries to your classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html), so please provide more info regarding how you are executing your program.

if from the command line, you can add libraries to the classpath via

`java -classpath path/lib.jar ...`

Comment: Google Collections is sort-of deprecated now, replaced by the Guava project (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Comment: i'm not the one referencing it ;)

Answer (score 3):

For me, in addition to selecting the jar - selenium-java-2.45.0.jar, I had to select all the jars in the "libs" folder under selenium root folder.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, but it was resolved if you add the libraries of selenium (again if you haven't), if you are using INTELIJ

> project>projectStructure>Module>+>add the selenium jars (both from lib folder and outside ones.).

Same needs to be done for other IDE's as well, like eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to import some google code:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
```

And it's not finding it the class Function.  Check to make sure all the required libraries are in your build path, and that you typed the package correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and fail even after installing the 'selenium-server-standalone-version.jar', I think you need to install the guava and guava-gwt jar (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) as well. I added all of these jar, and finally it worked in my PC. Hope it works for others meeting this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please include all the jar files of selenium stand-alone and lib folder, then this error will resolved

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found that I forgot to add selenium-2.53.0/selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar file to my project's Reference library.

Answer (score 0):

When I caught the exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function` it was caused by errors in Project Libraries.

Please check it in your project settings. For Intellij IDEA go to **File - Project Structure** and select **Modules** tab. All I needed to do to resolve this exception was re-adding the selenium library

Answer (score 0):

After you extract your "selenium-java-.zip" file you need to configure your build path from your IDE. Import all the jar files under "lib" folder and both selenium standalone server & Selenium java version jar files.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try a simple class outside IDE and stuff. So downloaded selenium zip from website and run the class like this:

```
java -cp selenium-2.50.1/*:selenium-2.50.1/libs/*:. my/package/MyClass <params>
```

I had the issue that I initially used `lib` instead of `libs`. I **didn't** need to add selenium standalone jar. This is Java 8 that understands wildcards in classpath. I think java 7 would also do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and finally I found that I forgot to add the selenium-server-standalone-version.jar. I had only added the client jar, selenium-java-version.jar.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is for chrome  
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Testing_offical\\chromedriver.exe");
driver =new ChromeDriver();
this is for fire fox 
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",""D:\\Testing_offical\\geckodriver.exe"");
driver =new FirefoxDriver();
```

pattern :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","**Path of the gecko driver** ");
```

Note download gecko from here  :- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/