# Why my code drops this error?

Tags: java, selenium

Hello im using eclipse with JavaSE-1.6, JUnit 4 and selenium-java 2.43.0.
Idont know why it doesnt works.

I try to change the firefoxdriver for chromedriver or iedriver but itś the same.

My Code

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;



import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import Pages.Register;


public class RegisterNewUser {  


Register register;
WebDriver driver;


@Before
public void initiation(){       
        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        this.register = new Register (driver);  
        this.driver.get("http//:e-farmacity.com/customer/account/create/"); 

}

@Test
public void testRegisterNewUser() { 
    register.getLastNameTextBox().sendKeys("NewUser");
    register.getLastNameTextBox().sendKeys("Test");
    register.getEmailTextBox().sendKeys("test@lyracons.com");
    register.getDayTextBox().sendKeys("09");
    register.getMonthTextBox().sendKeys("03");
    register.getYearTextBox().sendKeys("1993");
    List<WebElement> listOfGender = register.getGenderRadioButtons();
    listOfGender.get(0).click();
    register.getDniTextBox().sendKeys("38146782");
    register.getTelTextBox().sendKeys("221123123");
    register.getPassTextBox().sendKeys("prueba123");
    register.getConfirmPassTextBox().sendKeys("prueba123");
    register.getSuscriptionRadioButton().click();
    register.getSubmitButton().click(); 

}

 @After 
 public void finishtest() {

     this.driver.close();
 }
```

}

The error

```
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
at test.RegisterNewUser.initiation(RegisterNewUser.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
                                                                                                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
... 25 more

java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.RegisterNewUser.finishtest(RegisterNewUser.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
```

Comment: CLASSPATH issue.  Find the JAR that contains that class and add it to your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: Try to search for this solution more hard it is common problem.

Answer (score 1):

Itś fixed, it was that i havnt got the selenium-server-standalone. 
THankyou