# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function + selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run the below code in Eclipse Luna with Selenium JAR's

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Hello_Class {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    }
}
```

I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
at Hello_Class.main(Hello_Class.java:8) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

I have added all the Selenium Jars:
1.selenium-java-2.45.0.jar
2.selenium-java-2.45.0-srcs
3. All the JARS in Lib

---

Edit 1

Class Path is set - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
I have added tried adding _selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar and guava-18.0.jar

I have installed Eclipse Luna 64 Bit and Java 1.7.0_75 ..........

I am still getting the error not sure what else can I try now

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code, please make sure the classpath  is proper and required files are added into it. for more reference please check the link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function

Comment: Instead of adding selenium-java-2.45.0 add selenium-server 2.45, it contains al the needed jars bundled up in it. For using selenium-java u will need to add other jars as well.

Comment: @RupeshShinde - Class Path is set - _C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\_  I have added tried adding  _selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar_ and _guava-18.0.jar_ I have installed Eclipse Luna 64 Bit and Java 1.7.0_75 .......... I am still getting the error not sure what else can I try now

Comment: FWIW, I found that Maven had not completely downloaded the guava jar. I deleted it from my internal repo and rebuilt, and it worked.