# How to use java -cp and -jar in a togther

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying the following:

```
java -cp <path to the additional required jar > -jar <jarname>.jar
```

I am still getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running the above command.
Looks like it still cannot find the external jar mentioned after -cp.
Is that the correct syntax while giving the java command?

Comment: Which class is not found?

Comment: You can't. The options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Then how do I include the external jar?

Comment: Cannot find this class: com/google/common/base/Function
This class is in the selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function) maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the -jar and -classpath options together. If you want to use the -jar option you need to add the second JAR file to the Class-path attribute in the manifest of the first JAR file.

Answer (score -1):

You could add the additional jar to the bootclasspath

```
 java -Xbootclasspath/a:additional_required.jar -jar main.jar
```

**example**

**Foo.java**

```
package foo;
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new bar.Bar();
    }
}
```

**Bar.java**

```
package bar;
public class Bar {
    public Bar() {
        System.out.println("foobar");
    }
}
```

**manifest.mf**

```
Main-Class: foo.Foo
```

Execute the commands

```
javac -d . Bar.java Foo.java
jar cf Bar.jar bar/
jar cmf manifest.mf Foo.jar foo/
java -Xbootclasspath/a:Bar.jar -jar Foo.jar
```

**output**

```
foobar
```

Comment: Getting the following error when using the above command:
Unrecognized option: -Xbootclasspath

Comment: @amolkale Most probably you have a typo. Check the step-by-step example in my answer.

Comment: -X are non-standard options it might happen that @amolkale is not using oracle's JVM, hence, not supporting such option.

Comment: @pabrantes Could be a possible explanation. The posted example works with the Oracle JRE and the OpenJDK JRE.

Comment: If someone voting down a correct answer it would be nice to know the reason for voting down.

Answer (score -1):

Given the following command you provide:

`java -cp <path to the additional required jar > -jar <jarname>.jar`

it will fail because the 'classpath' value must be a '**;**' separated value. So try adding a **;** after your classpath values. For example:

`java -cp A.jar;Bjar; -jar <jarname>.jar`

and it is mandatory even if you have only one jar file in you classpath string:

`java -cp A.jar; -jar <jarname>.jar`

Good Luck.