# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException is comming when running appium script

Tags: java, appium

I am very new to appium:

i wanted to run a code where in my device i open chrome and open a google.com:

```
  @BeforeMethod
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");
    capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "TA9330416L");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void launchWebsite()throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  }
```

but getting the following error:

> ?* FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
>           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
>             at WhatsApp.setUp(WhatsApp.java:36)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>             at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
>             at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
>             at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
>             at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:589)
>             at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
>             at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
>             at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>             at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>             at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
>             at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>             at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1246)
>             at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1171)
>             at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1066)
>             at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
>             at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
>             at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
>           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
>             at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>             at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>             ... 27 more
>
> SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
>   SKIPPED: launchWebsite*/

Comment: Check if [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function) solves your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this dependendcy jar https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: Added the jar, getting this error now: @BeforeMethod setUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:88)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:62)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:57)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
 at WhatsApp.setUp(WhatsApp.java:36)

Comment: Now this jar httpclient-4.0.jar is missing. Please search with the class name that is missing in google you will find which jar has it. For example -  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials this class is present in the jar which i specified above.

Comment: Thanks yes all the problems were with missing jars. It was a lot of them.Added them all now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have to created any test class? Error says no class definition found. You have to create on test class first and define functions in the class. I have not tried on the android browser but I have automated android hybrid and native apps using appium.

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class TestBrowser {

public AndroidDriver driver;

public TestBrowser() {
        //To do
}

@BeforeMethod
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "TA9330416L");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

  }

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if(driver!=null)
        driver.quit();
 }

  @Test
  public void launchWebsite()throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: He definitely must have added a class. I believe he has posted only Error prone area. The issue is that it is not able to find class `com.google.common.base.Function`which is not end user defined class.

Comment: Yes I have added the test class and I was just showing the error prone areas....I definitely think i have some issue with configurations.