# NoClassDefFoundError in Java: com/google/common/base/Function import using maven

Tags: maven, selenium

This question is related to [NoClassDefFoundError in Java: com/google/common/base/Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function)

I get the exact same error, but I didn't manually add jars, I used maven instead.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.48.2</version>
</dependency>
```

in the old post, someone used maven suggested adding another dependence of guava 15.0. I tried, but not work.
Is there a way to solve it only using maven without manually add selenium-server-standalone-version.jar?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to selenium-java, add dependency of "selenium-remote-driver"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.48.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
```