# Issue in launching the browser using Selenium Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to launch gmail application in Firefox, And I tried chrome as well. But I'm getting an error while running this application. Not sure about this error. And this error seems to be more specific to Java. Could anyone help me to resolve this? Please find the project structure and error message below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Opening the browser
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //Navigating to this url
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    //Maximizing the browser window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Closing the browser
    driver.close();
}
```

[image: Error Message]

[image]

Comment: try the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function, most probably classpath issue

Comment: Thanks Naveen. Actually, I missed to add all the libraries in the selenium project(I have added only Selenium 2.53 and Selenium 2.53 srcs  JAR)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine. If the path to `chromedriver.exe` is correct and the dependencies are well defined, the Chrome should be opened.

[Here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/ChromeTest.java) you can clone a working example of a JUnit test using WebDriver and Chrome.

Comment: Is it related to any Java exception?