# How Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.google.common.base.function will be handled in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.google.common.base.function will be handled in selenium

got this error when running through Webdriver.

```
public class Logintoaccount {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "d:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d://chromedriver.exe");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError in Java: com/google/common/base/Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the Selenium standalone server in your build path. Add the required version and you would be good to go...

```
selenium-server-standalone-version.jar
```

Comment: It is to be downloaded from somewhere? can you provide me the link please.

Answer (score 1):

Add ***selenium-server-standalone-version.jar*** file in the project. the issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the problem you are facing:

You have used the Annotation as @Before. Going by the documentation of TestNG you can only use the following Annotations starting with @Before :

1. @BeforeSuite
2. @BeforeClass
3. @BeforeTest
4. @BeforeGroups
5. @BeforeMethod

Use the one which suits your test strategy. This will solve your issue. Do remember to import the classes​ from TestNG only.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I am using Junit framework for running the suite. Can you please guide according to JUnit. TIA

Comment: @KapilBisht Your question doesn't mentions about Junit. I have tried to answer your question in the most generalized approach. Can you accept the answer as a solution to your Question & raise a new Junit specific query? I will be happy to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Dev Issue is resolved. I missed the selenium-server-standalone-version.jar file to add in the project. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use @BeforeTest instead of @Before, since this setup() is going to run at the beginning of the test.

Comment: Hi Sudheer I am using JUnit to run the suite. Can you Guide According to JUNIT please

Comment: Code wise am not seeing any issue, have you imported selenium-java-2.53.1.jar & selenium-java-2.53.1-srcs.jar in build path?

Comment: I am using latest version of Selenium webdriver (version 3.3.1). I feel the latest version of selenium has an issue with executing the test cases. please help

Comment: I missed the selenium-server-standalone-version.jar file to add in the project thats why it was throwing the error.