# running Test cases in TestNG framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, test-reporting

hello I am trying to run a test case in TestNG class where i can get reports and number test failed or passed test cases 
the below code works when ran in normal java class...

```
@Test
public void make() throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\sasy\\Desktop\\Akhil\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log","org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");
    driver.get("http://198.57.218.124/CRFGLSPL/Private/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fCRFGLSPL%2fPrivate%2fPatientOrganDamageIntermediateVisit.aspx%3fPatientID%3d2&PatientID=2");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail']")).sendKeys("nikhil@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword']")).sendKeys("maryme");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit']")).click();
    //WebElement ID418=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edit41']"));
    //WebElement ID830=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edit40']"));
    WebElement ID969=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edit37']"));
    //WebElement ID472=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edit39']"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    ID969.click();
    driver.quit();

}
```

when the above code is ran as TestNG Test i am given following error

> FAILED: make
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
>       at first.heha.make(heha.java:16)

Comment: you need to run it from testng.xml > run as TestNG suite

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function seems similar to your issue

Comment: If your question is answered to your liking please consider marking one of the answers as the answer: [How to mark a question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

The jar file having the class `com.google.common.base.Function`, which you most probably did not add to your classpath.
Add Guava jar file to build path

Check to make sure all the required selenium ,testNg libraries are in your build path

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works fine with TestNG  I've tried it , all you need to do is to include the TeseNG Jars in your Class path you can do this manually by downloading TestNG jars and adding it to your classpath or Simply add TestNG dependency in your pom.xml if you are using Maven

If you are using maven to run your tests

Add below dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: you are welcome 
could you please choose this as the correct answer