# Writing into Web Page using java

Tags: java, selenium

So I'm trying to open a Web Page (google.com), write in search box some searching word and submit (the last part is still not done)

here's my code (using intellij):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;


public class First {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
        {
          try{
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://google.com"));
          }catch (IOException | java.net.URISyntaxException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    element.sendKeys("best puding ever");
  }
}
```

The web page opens, waits 10 seconds but no text inserted.
my error at the end:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
   com/google/common/base/Function
  at First.main(First.java:33)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    com.google.common.base.Function
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   ... 1 more
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

any idea?

Comment: How do you run this code? Are you developing a plugin for IntelliJ?

Comment: not developing plugins,
just added selenium-java-3.4.0.zip

Comment: could be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need Desktop object to open the browser, the webDriver can and should do it for you. You just need to call .get() method. 
With modifications mentioned above and by adding dependency for *selenium-chrome-driver* and *selenium-api* I can successfully run your example

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("http://google.com");
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
      element.sendKeys("best puding ever");
    }
```

My pom.xml file (you may need to use similar dependency in gradle since you using intellij):
    `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>`