# Firefox browser imports not working even gecko driver is used

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using Selenium 3.3.1 with Gecko driver to launch Firefox. I'm getting below error when i run my testng test.if i upgrade to 3.4.0 Firefox driver not working. imports not shown.

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function" - Exception
```

Can some one please provide the exact code for launching Firefox latest with selenium 3.4

Comment: It seems there is an answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError in Java: com/google/common/base/Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134953/noclassdeffounderror-in-java-com-google-common-base-function)